# ER Relationship Total and Partial Participation Example

Tags: database-design, erd

I am trying to understand partial and total participation.

Given the statement:

> "Each restaurant must have one or more dishes and each dish must be provided by exact one restaurant."

The below text is my current guess of how this would be written out...

`Restaurant ==(1)== Provide ==(n)== Dish`

...where `Restaurant` and `Dish` are entities and `Provide` is the relationship.

Is this correct?